# How to grab values of checkboxes in an array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div as follows:

```
<div class="questionholder" id="question5" style="display:none">
        <div>
            <h5>Select all that apply</h5>
            <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementColor" name="ID1element" value="color"><label for="ID1elementColor"><p class="radioChoice">Color</p></label>
            <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementHeight" name="ID1element" value="height"><label for="ID1elementHeight"><p class="radioChoice">Height</p></label>
            <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementWeight" name="ID1element" value="weight"><label for="ID1elementWeight"><p class="radioChoice">Weight</p></label>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="holdButtons">   
            <a class="text2button" onclick="displayquestion(6);">Next</a>
        </div>
```

The user is expected to select all the checkboxes that apply to his situation. Let's assume he selects all 3.

When he clicks "Next", the function displayquestion(); will fire.

```
function displayquestion(a) {
    var Elements = '';
    var b = a - 1;
    Elements = document.querySelector("#question" + b + " input[name=ID1element]").value;
}
```

Basically, the function is meant to store all the checked values into var Elements, which is meant to be an array.

However, I'm only getting the value of the first selected answer instead of an array of all selected answers.

How do I grab all the selected answers into an array?

No jQuery please.

Comment: querySelector only returns one element

Answer (score 2):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get an array-like `NodeList` instead of `querySelector`, and then you can use `Array.from` to transform that `NodeList` into an array containing only the `.value` of the selected inputs:

```js
function displayquestion(a) {
  const b = a - 1;
  const elements = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#question' + b + ' input:checked'),
    input => input.value
  );
  console.log(elements);
}
```

```html
<div class="questionholder" id="question5">
  <div>
    <h5>Select all that apply</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementColor" name="ID1element" value="color"><label for="ID1elementColor"><p class="radioChoice">Color</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementHeight" name="ID1element" value="height"><label for="ID1elementHeight"><p class="radioChoice">Height</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementWeight" name="ID1element" value="weight"><label for="ID1elementWeight"><p class="radioChoice">Weight</p></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holdButtons">
  <a class="text2button" onclick="displayquestion(6);">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of I would make a variable for your 
    `<a class="text2button">Next</a>`. And I have removed the 
    `onclick="displayquestion(6)"` from your html.

Here is the variable.

```
var text2button = document.getElementsByClassName("text2button")[0];
text2button.addEventListener("click", displayquestion);
```

Here we have the function, so what I've done is.

I have created a variable `var elements = [];` Which is a empty array.

Then I create this variable `var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("input5");`
This variable gets all the inputs with class **input5**.

Next I would loop through each of the inputs from the `var inputs`. Like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   if (inputs[i].checked) {
      elements.push(inputs[i].value);
   }
}
```

So what I do here is loop through each input `for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)` and then I check if any of the inputs are checked `if (inputs[i].checked)`, then I push them to the array `var elements` with `elements.push(inputs[i].value);`.

And then I use `console.log(elements);` so show it in the console.

Check out the snippet below to see it in effect.

Hope this helps.

```js
var text2button = document.getElementsByClassName("text2button")[0];
text2button.addEventListener("click", displayquestion);

function displayquestion() {
  var elements = [];
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("input5");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      elements.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
  }

  console.log(elements);
}
```

```html
<div class="questionholder" id="question5">
  <div>
    <h5>Select all that apply</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementColor" name="ID1element" value="color"><label for="ID1elementColor"><p class="radioChoice">Color</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementHeight" name="ID1element" value="height"><label for="ID1elementHeight"><p class="radioChoice">Height</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementWeight" name="ID1element" value="weight"><label for="ID1elementWeight"><p class="radioChoice">Weight</p></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holdButtons">
  <a class="text2button">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that you can use for that:

I haven't changed anything in your HTML structure. Except I have removed the `display: none;` from the style attribute of the class `questionholder`.

```html
<script>
  function displayquestion(b) {
    let checkboxList = document.querySelectorAll("#question" + b + " input:checked");
    let obj = [];
    if (checkboxList.length > 0) { //Code works only if some checbox is checked
      checkboxList.forEach(function(item) {
        obj.push(item.value); //Contains the value of all the selected checkboxes.
      });
    }
    console.log(obj); //array list containing all the selected values
  }
</script>
<div class="questionholder" id="question5" style="">
  <div>
    <h5>Select all that apply</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementColor" name="ID1element" value="color"><label for="ID1elementColor"><p class="radioChoice">Color</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementHeight" name="ID1element" value="height"><label for="ID1elementHeight"><p class="radioChoice">Height</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="ID1elementWeight" name="ID1element" value="weight"><label for="ID1elementWeight"><p class="radioChoice">Weight</p></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holdButtons">
  <a class="text2button" onclick="displayquestion(5);">Next</a>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4fbrsed/) link for that.

I hope this is helpful.